# Tensorflow: To know whether one epoch is completed in iteration

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow's queue as the input for training a network. I set `num_epoches` to 10 and `batch_size` to 100. Since I don't know how many samples stored in the TFRecords file, so that I don't know in how many iterations one epoch is finished.

I do know there is method using `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator` to pre-read the TFRecords file, to get the total number of samples. However when the TFRecords file is large, this method is bad because it must loop the whole file and count the samples. I am wondering whether Tensorflow has its own way to report one epoch is finished?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this. The only place that could do this is `string_input_producer`.

Comment: this question provides a way to find out that value, and this answer provides some insight regarding this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/42494381/2005810