# How to use TensorFlow tf.train.string_input_producer to produce several epochs data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

When I want to use `tf.train.string_input_producer` to load data for 2 epochs, I used

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames=['data.csv'], num_epochs=2, shuffle=True)

col1_batch, col2_batch, col3_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([col1, col2, col3], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,\min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
```

But then I found that this op did not produce what I want.

It can only produce each sample in `data.csv` for 2 times, but the generated order is not clearly. For example, 3 line data in `data.csv`

```
[[1]
[2]
[3]]
```

it will produce (which each sample just appear 2 times, but the order is optional)

```
[1]
[1]
[3]
[2]
[2]
[3]
```

but what I want is (each epoch is separate, shuffle in each epoch)

```
(epoch 1:)
[1]
[2]
[3]
(epoch 2:)
[1]
[3]
[2]
```

In addition, how to know when 1 epoch was done? Is there some flag variables? Thanks!

my code is here.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_defaults = [['1'], ['1'], ['1']]  
    col1, col2, col3 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults, field_delim='-')
    # col1 = list(map(int, col1.split(',')))
    # col2 = list(map(int, col2.split(',')))
    return col1, col2, col3

def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=1):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
  col1,col2,col3 = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)

  min_after_dequeue = 10
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  col1_batch, col2_batch, col3_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [col1, col2, col3], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
    min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
  return col1_batch, col2_batch, col3_batch

filenames=['1.txt']
batch_size = 3
num_epochs = 1
a1,a2,a3=input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  # start populating filename queue
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
      a, b, c = sess.run([a1, a2, a3])
      print(a, b, c)
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training, epoch reached')
  finally:
    coord.request_stop()

  coord.join(threads)
```

my data is like

```
1,2-3,4-A
7,8-9,10-B
12,13-14,15-C
17,18-19,20-D
22,23-24,25-E
27,28-29,30-F
32,33-34,35-G
37,38-39,40-H
```

Comment: Can you add the code that generates tensors `col1`, `col2`, `col3`? The way the code is written indicates that you shuffle at the end of the pipeline so it will all mix up together

Comment: I added my code and data.@MZHm

Comment: You might want to have a look at this answer for a rather similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526962/4282745

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for your reply! As you write before, tf enqueued all epochs together before load the data if the data_size is small, so the `epoch_op="input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs:0"` did not properly work as it is always the last one. And the problem is not yet solved as the shuffle is still shuffle among all the enqueued data rather then only one epoch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Nicolas observes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44550303/3574081), the [`tf.train.string_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) API does not give you the ability to detect when the end of an epoch is reached; instead it concatenates together all epochs into one long batch. For this reason, we recently added (in TensorFlow 1.2) the [`tf.contrib.data` API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/data), which makes it possible to express more sophisticated pipelines, including your use case.

The following code snippet shows how you would write your program using `tf.contrib.data`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size):
    # Define a `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` for iterating over one epoch of the data.
    dataset = (tf.contrib.data.TextLineDataset(filenames)
               .map(lambda line: tf.decode_csv(
                    line, record_defaults=[['1'], ['1'], ['1']], field_delim='-'))
               .shuffle(buffer_size=10)  # Equivalent to min_after_dequeue=10.
               .batch(batch_size))

    # Return an *initializable* iterator over the dataset, which will allow us to
    # re-initialize it at the beginning of each epoch.
    return dataset.make_initializable_iterator() 

filenames=['1.txt']
batch_size = 3
num_epochs = 10
iterator = input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size)

# `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` represent the next element to be retrieved from the iterator.    
a1, a2, a3 = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(num_epochs):
        # Resets the iterator at the beginning of an epoch.
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)

        try:
            while True:
                a, b, c = sess.run([a1, a2, a3])
                print(a, b, c)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            # This will be raised when you reach the end of an epoch (i.e. the
            # iterator has no more elements).
            pass                 

        # Perform any end-of-epoch computation here.
        print('Done training, epoch reached')
```

Comment: Why do we use exceptions for control flow? (i.e. `except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`)

Comment: Exceptions are the only mechanism that TensorFlow currently has signal that the requested values have not been computed. (It's similar to how Python uses the `StopIteration` exception to signal the end of an iterator in its own iterator protocol.) It would certainly be possible to wrap this in some library code, and I suggested one way of doing this in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7951#issuecomment-303546037).

Comment: why not simply `while not sess.run(epoch_done): ...`?
`epoch_done` is a variable that is set by the queue and reset by `iterator.initializer`

Comment: MZHm's solution seems to be very elegant. `epoch_done` could be the equivalent of the `global_step`variable.

Comment: You might be able to build something like that on top of the raw `tf.contrib.data.Iterator` class. Writing iterators that perform side effects (like setting an auxiliary variable) is a bit hairy, but it's possible.

Comment: @mrry@MZHM@Nicolas Thanks for your reply. It is properly solved. In addition, is there some method for me to directly obtained `[list(int), list(int), int]` format rather then post-processing `[string, string, int]` after reading the csv?

Comment: @danche I'm not sure I understand what the data format is... the code uses a field delimiter of `'-'` but the example `data.csv` in your question looks quite different. What is the content of the `string` values returned?

Comment: @mrry data format has 3 cols like `1,2-3,4-0`, The ahead 2 cols are index, the index col length is unfixed, last col is labels. So I want `[list(int), list(int), int]` format after `decode_csv` func. But now I can only obtained `[string, string,int]` now.

Comment: You could apply `tf.decode_csv(..., field_delim=',')` to the first and second columns returned by the first call to `tf.decode_csv()`. (It might be easier to convert the `lambda` in the `map()` call into a small function.)

Comment: @mmry this op is need to know exactly the columns of each cols returned, but the length is not fixed...

Comment: To handle variable-length sequences, you can return `(tf.string_split(col1, ',').values, tf.string_split(col2, ',').values, col3)` (assuming `col1` etc. are the return values from the initial `tf.decode_csv()`).

Comment: @mrry I tried this before. but a error occured `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'StringSplit' (op: 'StringSplit') with input shapes: [], [].`

Comment: @mrry Excuse me. When I use `tf.contrib.data` to load data. I found `dataset.shuffle` just shuffle the `buffer_size` data, It is not shuffle the whole dataset. Is there any solution could handle this?

Comment: @mmry after obtaining the batch, i notice the data is transposed, is there a way we can specify transpose during batch processing ? It seems ridiculous to use python libs for transposing after all the pain we went thru to patch up the TF batch processing :)

Comment: @danche `Dataset.shuffle()` maintains a fixed size buffer... depending on the size of your dataset, you could set the buffer size to be larger than the number of examples and it will shuffle everything. (Although it's not perfect, many large scale training jobs approximate this by randomly shuffling the dataset offline before training, then using `Dataset.shuffle()` to add some more randomness.)

Comment: @bicepjai I assume you could use `tf.transpose()`, but I'm not really sure what problem you are facing. Perhaps it would be better to ask a new question?

Comment: Yeah, I am new to tensorflow objects and was confused. Debugging with static graph flow needs patience :) thanks. I ended up doing the same.

Comment: @mrry Thanks, I'll take a try.

Comment: @mrry, this is a great example and much clearer than the docs. It would be even better (though perhaps beyond the scope of the original question) if you added a training step of a simple model like a [softmax regression](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/get_started/mnist/beginners), i.e. show how to connect a, b, c to tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44526962/4282745) to a similar question.

The short story is that:

- if `num_epochs` > 1, all the data is enqueued at the same time and suffled independently of the epoch,
- so you don't have the ability to monitor which epoch is being dequeued.

What you could do is the first suggestion in the quoted answer, which is to work with `num_epochs` == 1, and reinitialise the local queue variables (and obviously not the model variables) in each run.

```
init_queue = tf.variables_initializer(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES, scope='input_producer'))
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
for e in range(num_epochs):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(init_queue) # reinitialize the local variables in the input_producer scope
       # start populating filename queue
       coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
       threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
       try:
           while not coord.should_stop():
               a, b, c = sess.run([a1, a2, a3])
               print(a, b, c)
       except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
           print('Done training, epoch reached')
       finally:
           coord.request_stop()

       coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Thanks again. I tried this solution before, but I think it is not elegant enough :P. Maybe it is the most practical way, I think that tf should add some parameters to solve this problems.

Comment: In this way, every epoch I need to initial variables, but this op will produce some other problems to the models, right?

Comment: I agree. Anyway according this comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4535#issuecomment-283181862
queues are not the way we should handle data in the future.

Comment: In this way, any epoch you initialise local variables in the `input_producer` scope. So it should be the queue variables (unless of a scope collision...).