# In TensorFlow, how to decode 2 nested CSVs with different field delimiters to list object?

Tags: csv, tensorflow, neural-network

For example, for line `1,2-3,4-0`, now I use

```
line = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[['1'], ['1'], [1]], field_delim='-')
```

to produce `[string, string, int]`, but I want `[list(int), list(int), int]` at this step rather then post-processing it after reading csv.

How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code works. It just decodes again the 2 first values of your line using (but it assumes that all your rows have the same format: 2 lists of length 2 and an integer).

```
line = tf.Variable('1,2-3,4-0')
line = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[['1'], ['1'], [1]], field_delim='-')

# Let us decode the first and the second values of the line
x =  tf.decode_csv(line[0], record_defaults=[[1], [1]], field_delim=',')
y =  tf.decode_csv(line[1], record_defaults=[[1], [1]], field_delim=',')

# Let us run the previous ops
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(x))       # print [1, 2]
    print(sess.run(y))       # print [3, 4]
    print(sess.run(line[2])) # print 0
```

EDIT: as per comment,

you can try [tf.string_split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_split):

```
def decode(line):
    line = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[['1'], ['1'], [1]], field_delim='-')

    x = tf.string_split(line[:1], ",").values
    y = tf.string_split(line[1:2], ",").values

    x = tf.string_to_number(x, tf.int32)
    y = tf.string_to_number(y, tf.int32)

    return x, y, line[2]

line = tf.Variable('12-3,4-0')
x, y, z = decode(line)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(x)) # print [12]
    print(sess.run(y)) # print [3 4]
    print(sess.run(z)) # print 0
```

EDIT2: Simplified `decode` func.

Comment: The first 2 columns are not fixed length, may be `1,2-3,4-5` or `1-2,3-1`

Comment: Thanks, it works. use `x = tf.string_split(line[:1], ",")` can obtain the one cols values in SparseTensor. But is not very directly enough~

Comment: It works good in my terminal. But when I run the script python file which includes the code above, python will crash...@Nicolas

Comment: What's the exception and your TF version? It works fine for me on version 1.0.1.

Comment: I forget the exact version, but sure 1.2+. I used the code [tf.contrib.data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549245/how-to-use-tensorflow-tf-train-string-input-producer-to-produce-several-epochs-d), and it crashed on win10 paltform..@Nicolas

Comment: I used this code [tf.contrib.data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44551409/5496463) mrry provided.

Comment: Everytime I run the script, it just stop run the `sess.run()` int the aforementioned codes...

Comment: Thx. My view is that it should be a different SO question as it seems quite far away from the initial question. Would you mind putting your edit into its own question? I'll take a look meantime.

Comment: Sure, I edit my question and add a new issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44582169/5496463) @Nicolas