# How can I shuffle a whole dataset with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, shuffle

Now I use following function for shuffling

```
from tensorflow.contrib import data
def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size):
    # Define a `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` for iterating over one epoch of the data.
    dataset = data.TextLineDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(decode_func)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)  # Equivalent to min_after_dequeue=10000.
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    # Return an *initializable* iterator over the dataset, which will allow us to
    # re-initialize it at the beginning of each epoch.
    return dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

But it will just shuffle data at the amount of `buffer_size` and it will fill `buffer` in an order.

My data is enormous which I can not set `buffer_size` too big. Is there any other solutions I can shuffle the whole datasets?

Comment: Maybe in future parts of your code you will transform to a `Tensor`? If the answer is yes, you can use `tf.random_shuffle`.

Comment: The part transfer to `Tensor` is just the `batch_part` rather than all data...

Comment: Will creating a filename queue with shuffle like `tf.train.string_input_producer' before the data queue, address your problem?

Comment: Thks, but this will cause other problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549245/how-to-use-tensorflow-tf-train-string-input-producer-to-produce-several-epochs-d

Comment: Do you mind the shuffling being a preprocessing step before the model is trained? If not, look into the `shuf` unix command.

Answer (score 8):

Currently there is no support in Dataset API for shuffling a whole Dataset (greater then 10k examples). According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14857) thread, the common approach is:

> 1. Randomly shuffle the entire data once using a
>      MapReduce/Spark/Beam/etc. job to create a set of roughly equal-sized
>      files ("shards").
> 2. In each epoch:
>
>    a. Randomly shuffle the list of shard filenames, using Dataset.list_files(...).shuffle(num_shards).
>
>    b. Use dataset.interleave(lambda filename: tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename), cycle_length=N) to mix together records from N different shards.
>
>    c. Use dataset.shuffle(B) to shuffle the resulting dataset. Setting B might require some experimentation, but you will probably want to set it to some value larger than the number of records in a single shard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shuffle all data sets, you have this method:

> Note: shuffle(dataset.cardinality()) loads the full dataset into
> memory so that it can be shuffled. This will cause a memory overflow
> (OOM) error if the dataset is too large, so full-shuffle should only
> be used for datasets that are known to fit in the memory, such as
> datasets of filenames or other small datasets.

But you can see that it will cause an overflow of memory (OOM), if you don't have enough memory.

So I did this method, to play with the memory.

**Please Note:**

- I use it for displaying my test dataset or exploring.
- *I do not recommend using it for training and validation.* Please use Tensorflow's native methods in this case.

```
    def tf_shuffle_dataset(dataset, batch_size, seed):
        """
        Shuffles a TensorFlow dataset memory-preservingly using a batch-based method and also shuffles the batches themselves.

        Args:
        - dataset (tf.data.Dataset): The input dataset to shuffle.
        - batch_size (int): Size of each batch.
        - seed (int, optional): Seed for shuffle reproducibility.

        Returns:
        - tf.data.Dataset: Shuffled dataset.

        Example:
        --------
        Let's consider a dataset: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and batch_size = 2.

        1. The dataset is divided into the following batches:
           [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]

        2. Each batch is shuffled. Let's assume the shuffled batches are:
           [2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5], [8, 7], [10, 9] (Note: The actual shuffle might differ)

        3. The order of these shuffled batches is then shuffled. Let's assume the shuffled order is:
           [4, 3], [2, 1], [8, 7], [10, 9], [6, 5] (Note: The actual shuffle might differ)

        4. These batches are concatenated together to give the final shuffled dataset:
           [4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 10, 9, 6, 5]
        """
        if not isinstance(dataset, tf.data.Dataset):
            raise ValueError("The provided dataset is not an instance of tf.data.Dataset.")

        # Split the dataset into batches
        num_elements = sum(1 for _ in dataset)
        num_batches = num_elements // batch_size

        batches = [dataset.skip(i * batch_size).take(batch_size) for i in range(num_batches)]

        # Shuffle each batch individually
        shuffled_batches = [batch.shuffle(buffer_size=batch_size, seed=seed) for batch in batches]

        # Shuffle the order of batches themselves
        batch_order = tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(num_batches), seed=seed)

        # Merge the shuffled batches to create the final dataset
        shuffled_dataset = shuffled_batches[0]
        for i in tqdm(batch_order[1:], desc="Shuffling dataset", unit="batch"):
            shuffled_dataset = shuffled_dataset.concatenate(shuffled_batches[i.numpy()])

        return shuffled_dataset
```